# Asking for branch transfer in the event of moving to another town

Tags: job-change, internal-transfer

I'm considering moving to another town for family reasons, and this would take me too far from my current office.

The new town has a severe lack of job opportunities, but there is a branch of my company relatively close to where I would live.

How can I ask about the possibility of an internal transfer without giving the impression that I would just leave if not given what I want?

Comment: Do you actually plan to leave if you don't get that transfer?

Comment: @MaskedMan There is a remote chance I would leave anyway, but as I said there are very few job opportunities where I'd like to move, so I'd would probably stay where I am and look for other solutions

Answer (score 5):

You really need to ask your manager or HR department.

> I'm considering the possibility moving to xyz, would I be able to work out of the local office there?

And discuss how this might change your role/responsibilities.

Or this might not be possible, but this really depends on the situation.

Comment: Yep, asking is about the only way.

Comment: My fear is that starting with "I'm moving" would cut every chance of keeping my current job. I'm still evaluating if I'll move or not, and keeping this job is one of the deciding factors

Comment: Change it to "I'm thinking about moving to".  If you let your boss/HR know that you remaining as an employee is important to you, they shouldn't have any kind reason to fire you.